# How did Eren transform into a Titan without causing self-injury (Season 4, Ep. 5)?

Tags: attack-on-titan

So at the end of Season 4, Episode 5, we see Eren becomes a Titan while talking to Reiner. He didn't cause any self-harm, so how did he transform? Should it be assumed that they just didn't show him causing self-injury?

Any answer is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you see his hand is already bleeding before he shakes reiner's hand and goes boom. he was just waiting to activate his power[image]